# Quebra de linha com altura de imagens diferentes, Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-3

Estou com um problema em minha Grid com quebra de linha, as imagens vem de um banco de dados e são de alturas diferentes, umas horizontais e outras verticais.

Estou usando o bootstrap.

Tenho esse código

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4 borda_cat">

<a href="produtos/<?php echo $row_categoria2["url"] ?>/<?php echo $row_subcategoria2["url"] ?>/<?php echo $row_produtos["url"] ?>" class="hvr-bubble-top"><img src="uploads/<?php echo $row_fotos_produtos["nome"]?>" class="img-responsive"></a>  

</div>                    
</div>
```

no site as imagens ficam assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faria para alinhar as colunas sendo que as alturas são diferentes?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer thumbnails. Pode fazer "manualmente" recortando as imagens e salvando as thumbs, ou pode fazer "virtual" que seria em tempo de execução, uma biblioteca excelente para se fazer isto é o [Smartcrop](https://github.com/jwagner/smartcrop.js/).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.borda_cat').each(function(i, el){
    crop($('img.img-responsive', el).get(0), $(el).width());
  });
});

function crop(image, size) {
  console.log('crop',image);
  var options = {debug: false, width: size, height: size};
  var _img = new Image;

  _img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
  _img.onload = function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      var img = this;
      console.log('start crop');
      smartcrop.crop(img, options, function(result) {

        var crop = result.topCrop;
        var canvas = $('<canvas />')[0];
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = options.width;
        canvas.height = options.height;
        ctx.drawImage(img, crop.x, crop.y, crop.width, crop.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        $(image).hide().after(canvas);

        console.log('crop end');
      });
    }.bind(this), 100);
  };
  _img.src = image.src;
}
```

Comment: as imagens não podem ser recortadas, pois os tamanhos são reias do prosuto, nao teria como fazer com css, jquery ou bootstrap?

Comment: Outra solução seria padronizar o tamanho das imagens, na web não existe "magia", ou você padroniza antes de colocar lá, ou você padroniza lá, tem que ver o que vai te dar menos trabalho e o que te atende melhor. Você ainda pode juntar isso com um lightbox para ver a imagem original...